# How to pass proxy config into Airflow S3 connection

Tags: airflow

I have a ec2 server running airflow which I have to use a proxy for all external https requests. The following function works with in the dag.

```
import boto3
from botocore.config import Config

def get_files(**context):

    s3 = boto3.client('s3',config=Config(proxies={'https': 'mycorpsproxy.com:3128'}))
    s3_bucket = "some_bucket"
    paginator = s3.get_paginator("list_objects")
    page_iterator = paginator.paginate(
        Bucket=s3_bucket, Prefix="folder_like_prefix/"
    current_files = []
    for page in page_iterator:
        if 'Contents' not in page:
            continue
        for object in page['Contents']:
            current_files.append(object['Key'])
    return current_files
```

But I don't want to have to hard code that proxy in every dag. I would like to use a s3 hook but am unable to find what to place in the extra field in airflow connections to make it work.

I have tried a few variations, such as

[image: Airflow connection web interface prefilled out with S3]

but get json errors when I run the dag

```
[2019-11-04 14:08:01,266] {logging_mixin.py:112} INFO - [2019-11-04 14:08:01,266] {connection.py:296} ERROR - Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/airflow/models/connection.py", line 294, in extra_dejson
    obj = json.loads(self.extra)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/json/__init__.py", line 354, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/json/decoder.py", line 339, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/json/decoder.py", line 357, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
[2019-11-04 14:08:01,267] {logging_mixin.py:112} INFO - [2019-11-04 14:08:01,266] {connection.py:297} ERROR - Failed parsing the json for conn_id s3_airflow
```

Comment: Very curious / also working on this problem. I don't have a fix yet, but flagging for you in case it's helpful / leads to an answer that I don't even have the proxy setup in the S3 connection and am experiencing the exact same error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the documentation is written:
config_kwargs: Additional kwargs used to construct a botocore.config.Config passed to boto3.client and boto3.resource.

See: https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-amazon/stable/connections/aws.html

So you can add extra args in UI like this:
{"host":"https://target:port", "aws_access_key_id":"my_key_id", "aws_secret_access_key": "my_access_key", "config_kwargs": {"proxies":{"http": 'my.insane.proxy:8080', "https": 'my.insane.proxy:8080'}}}